# Nmap - UDP scan does not work well with OS Detection

Tags: nmap, scanning, network-scan

I'm trying to run TCP & UDP scan combined but I have different outcomes when it comes to detected host details (insufficient details to OS when compared to pure TCP scan).

I run TCP only and TCP_UDP combined for comparison of the output:

TCP_Only: nmap -sV -T5 -O -v
Output for 10.101.137.254:

Nmap scan report for 10.101.137.254
Host is up (0.0042s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT    STATE  SERVICE    VERSION
113/tcp closed ident
179/tcp open   tcpwrapped
MAC Address: 00:09:0F:09:00:10 (Fortinet)
Device type: general purpose
Running (JUST GUESSING): Linux 3.X (85%)
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
Aggressive OS guesses: Linux 3.2 - 3.8 (85%)
No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).
Uptime guess: 10.314 days (since Sun Feb 25 03:31:24 2024)
Network Distance: 1 hop
TCP Sequence Prediction: Difficulty=259 (Good luck!)
IP ID Sequence Generation: Randomized

TCP_UDP_Combined: nmap -sS -sU -sV -T5 -O -v
Output for 10.101.137.254:

Nmap scan report for 10.101.137.254
Host is up (0.0057s latency).
Skipping host 10.101.137.254 due to host timeout

As you can see per outputs from combined scan I'm not getting proper "Nmap scan report" (MAC,OS,ETC.)
Maybe I use wrong sequence/order of switches, or... ?